# OperationException causing bad request error

Tags: java, android, firebase, debugging, firebase-authentication

I've created a login page which successfully allows users to login/logout and create accounts.  It worked completely fine.  The code has no issues.

I later decided to include a MapActivity in my project to test some stuff out but afterwards, I decided to remove it.  Ever since removing it, it won't allow users to login to their accounts.  I'm getting the `Error: An internal error has occurred [BAD REQUEST]` error.

Things I've tried:

- I've enabled Email/Password on Firebase console.
- Removed anything and everything related to MapActivity from my project.
- Invalidate Caches/Restart.
- Running my program on different emulators.

What can I do to rectify this problem?  If you want to see code, let me know.  Thanks in advance.

Here's `LoginActivity.java` file:

```
package com.example.name.myapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText loginEmailText;
    private EditText loginPassText;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private Button loginRegBtn;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar loginProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginEmailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        loginPassText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_confirm_pass);
        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        loginRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_reg_btn);
        loginProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

        loginRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String loginEmail = loginEmailText.getText().toString();
                String loginPass = loginPassText.getText().toString();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(loginEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(loginPass)) {
                    loginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail, loginPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                sendToMain();
                            } else {
                                String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error : " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            loginProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser != null) {
            sendToMain();
        }
    }

    private void sendToMain() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here's the exception I'm getting:

```
a06-07 08:54:38.591 2409-2943/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetExperimentTokensOperationCall
OperationException[Status{statusCode=No config packages for log source, or config package not registered, resolution=null}]
    at aelu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):32)
    at aelu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):66)
    at noj.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):40)
    at axja.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):2)
    at nsg.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):27)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at nya.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should always post your code that's relevant to the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry about that, posted it now.

Comment: have you added json config in your app? or registered the user

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I don't have a json config.  Yes, the user is the registered.

Comment: Have you done enough logging to know at what point this error happens?

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, I posted what I'm seeing in the logcat.

Comment: seems like google play service internal error, something is wrong with the configuration

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yeah, I don't know what to do. This is weirdest error I've ever came across.  It was working perfectly fine before, I have no clue how this happened out of no where.  That's software development for ya! lol

Comment: Right, but you haven't tried to narrow it down to a particular bit of code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson It's hard to tell because it was working perfectly fine before.  The code that I've posted is the one that worked 100%, but now it doesn't & I have no idea why.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your app.

Comment: @DougStevenson Tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using emulator or device? If are in genymotion, check play service version.

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio emulator

Comment: try update play service or try test in device

Answer (score 0):

If help, you can add other exception validations, for check problem:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
             if(task.isSuccessful())
              {
                  //-----------
    }else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {    
    }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_USER_DISABLED"))
    {
    }    
    else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND "))
        {
        }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED "))
        {
        }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN "))
        {
        }
        }
        });
```